# angularjs call watch when 2 arrays have been updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have made an angularjs directive for drawing a d3 force-directed graph. This graph gets updated periodically with new nodes and links.

Recently, I have noticed that when the graph gets updated, it is redrawn 2x which takes a lot of time.  Part of that is because I have to first update the node array, and then the edges array, and each trigger a redraw.  I would like watch to be called after BOTH have been updated.

I have seen a lot of questions for how to deal with watch for an `OR` relationship, but **I specifically only want redraw to happen after BOTH nodes `AND` links have been updated.**

Here is my current directive:

```js
graphs.directive('myGraph', [function () {

    function renderGraph(scope, elem) {

        drawGraph(scope.data, scope.data.params || {}, elem);

        scope.$watchCollection('data', function (newData) {
            drawGraph(newData, scope.data.params || {}, elem);
        });
    }

    function drawGraph(data, params, elem) {

        const rawSvg = elem.find(".svg")[0];

        forceDirectedGraph.create(data.nodes, data.links, data.nodeTypes, rawSvg, params);
    }

    return {
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'graph.html',
        link: renderGraph
    }
}]);
```

And here is how I update the graph:

```js
//initialization code:
$scope.graph = { links:[], nodes:[], params:{ /*stuff*/} }

//graph update code:
$http.get(url).then( function(response) {
    links = [];
    nodes = [];

    //process and format links and nodes for d3 from request

    $scope.graph.links = links;
    $scope.graph.nodes = nodes;

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options come to mind, none of them great -- although I'd lean towards #1. Not sure how ideal they are for your specific needs though:

***Option 1***

Add a new property to the `data` object called `shouldRedraw`. Set it to false at the beginning of the $http.get success callback. Set it to true after the data has been updated completed. In the $watch, only redraw if set:

```
//initialization code:
$scope.graph = { links:[], nodes:[], shouldRedraw:true, params:{ /*stuff*/} }

//graph update code:
$http.get(url).then( function(response) {
    $scope.graph.shouldRedraw = false;

    links = [];
    nodes = [];

    //process and format links and nodes for d3 from request

    $scope.graph.links = links;
    $scope.graph.nodes = nodes;
    $scope.graph.shouldRedraw = true;
});

// the watch
scope.$watchCollection('data', function (newData) {
    if (newData.shouldRedraw === true) {
        drawGraph(newData, scope.data.params || {}, elem);
    }
});
```

***Option 2***

Update your `myGraph` directive to accept the `links`, `nodes` and `params` values as separate scope inputs. Then $watch the `links` and `nodes` variables. Have a flag `isStagedForRedraw` that defaults to false. Whichever is updated first, `links` or `nodes`, will trigger the flag to be set, and the second will trigger the redraw and the flag to be unset:

```
var isStagedForRedraw = false;

scope.$watchGroup(['links', 'nodes'], function (newValues, oldValues, scope) {
    if (isStagedForRedraw) {
        drawGraph({links:scope.links, nodes:scope.nodes}, scope.data.params || {}, elem);
        isStagedForRedraw = false;
    } else {
        isStagedForRedraw = true;
    }
});
```

***Option 3***

Have the directive keep track of the `data` object like it does not, but also the JSONified values of the `data.links` and `data.nodes` values. On watch, JSONify the new values of `data.links` and `data.nodes`. If both changed, redraw and update the tracked JSONified values. If only one changed, don't do anything.

Comment: Thanks!  so results so far:  Option 2 did not like to show the graph when I first refreshed the page, but would show up on subsequent navigations to it.
Option 1 is what I am going with so far.  However, when I navigate away from a page and back to it, it still draws 2x :( .  But for the other cases (page stays open, graph gets updated from request & initial page load) it only draws once -- so there is progress.

Comment: It draws twice because (1) you are defaulting `shouldRedraw` to true when you first initialize the graph object and (2) because you are explicitly drawing the graph before you create the watch. In order to prevent it from drawing twice, simply default `shouldRedraw` to false:

`$scope.graph = { links:[], nodes:[], shouldRedraw:false, params:{ /*stuff*/} };`

Comment: I preemptively  set `draw` to false when creating the scope objects (cause otherwise you are 100% right) 
Just for fun took out the drawGraph statement outside the watch -- and everything seems to work!  I guess I needed that before, but not now.  Thanks much!